# Validate tar extraction

Tags: debian, tar

I have a script that processes large tar.bz2 and tar.gz files.

So the user doesn't think it has locked up they are piped in from pv:

```sh
pv redacted.tar.bz2 | tar -xj
pv redacted2.tar.gz | tar -xz
```

Problem is these files are large and takes time.  If a user decides to cancel the script operation the next time they run it it will have to start from the very beginning if if they cancelled it at 99%.

Is there are way of having it to check the files are already present on disk and only extract those that are missing?

Answer (score 1):

`-k` flag for tar sounds like what you would want. From the help section:

`-k    Keep (don't overwrite) existing files`

Comment: Thank you, however the -k option spams the screen with text.  After a bit of searching (which I should of done more of, admittedly) -k led me to --skip-old-files which is more appropriate.